# Is there a way to retrieve the manifest file I've uploaded to the seller dashboard for my add-in?

Tags: office-addins, office-store

I want to confirm my uploaded manifest and the office-id it contains, but when I've signed in to seller dashboard it only gives me the option to delete it. Is there any way where I can see the contents of my *current* manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download your manifest from Mcirosoft AppSource via this URL

https://store.office.com/app/download?assetid=WAXXXXXXXXX&cmu=en-US

Replace WAXXXXXXXXX with the asset ID of your add-in (visibile in the AppSource URL if you don't know it) and en-US with your add-in default language if different.